# How can I add 20% to a textbox value in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I want a textbox that will add on a 20% to the users input value.

For example if users input is £85.00 then it should show £102.00.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

```
    <TextBox LostFocus="JobPrice_LostFocus" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Price" Width="250" Name="JobPrice" PreviewTextInput="JobPrice_PreviewTextInput" />
```

Comment: Did you try to solve your problem? Any effort to show us?

Comment: Well, it's on you to do any calculations you want! ;-)

Comment: (1) What have you tried? What is not working? (2) It should be written to the same textbox? (3) What is the trigger for recalculating the value? You can't do it on keypress since you'd change the value the user is currently typing and thus will end up with an unusable control.

Comment: Sorry I am new to using c# and coding in general and thought I would jump in the deep end and try c#, a friend told me to use stackoverflow and that it is good for problems and help. I have searched google to try work out my problem. @Flater If possible it could maybe work when user clicks off of textbox ?

Comment: User clicks off of textbox then the percentage gets added

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this c# code:

```
private void TextBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        decimal CalculatedPrice = decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text) * 20 / 100 + decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        TextBox1.Text = CalculatedPrice.ToString();            
    }
```

Comment: Good answer.  Could you make it more readable though?  Like, only parse the text once?  Error checking if you think it's needed?  It may also be a part of the requirement that the display string is in a "money" format and that may need some explanation for the OP.

Comment: Dear Dan Rayson you are correct, I could add a sample how to limit the textbox to numbers only but looking at his XAML he added a PreviewTextInput event which he could use for text validation, since i'm not sure what codes he has so I try to answer only on the questions he asked.

Comment: Thank you @DarkTemplar was exactly what I was looking for